# How to import a file from different folder and with different file extensions or different file types in python and run them without error?

Tags: python, import, python-import, importerror, python-importlib

I'm trying to import a file called comodoinit.sh from a folder called av-utility and the file is a linux shell file with extension (.sh) . I want to import the comodoinit.sh file and run them without error in python . The python  file name is controlunit.py .

I tried to import it using the module sys and then import the folder and then import the module . But that didn't workout properly . The interpreter displays that no module named comodoinit.sh

```
import sys
sys.path.insert (1, 'D:\Projects\Codes\Projects\Sleek Security\Linux Security\av-utility')
import comodoinit.sh
```

I need to import the comodoinit.sh file and i need to run that file with another linux shell file without no errors in just one execution .

Answer (score 1):

your situation looks ambiguous
import is for .py files, not .sh
.sh files are for execution in linux
but your path tells you are coding in windows

in linux you can do os.popen('/path/to/comodoinit.sh') to execute a shell script
in windows you need to convert the .sh file to equivalent .bat file(not always possible) and do os.popen on that .bat file

Comment: The code does not bring error . The sys.popen() should be replaced with os.popen()

Comment: But it shows no output !!! Even for .cmd file it does not show's the desired output !!!

Comment: more information is  need to solve your  question . if you do not know how to bring  in information in the effective way ,  post the content of  comodoinit.sh in your question.